# How to find a diagonalizing basis of a matrix by using Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a $3\times 3$ matrix which I want to diagonalize, $A$.

So I want to find the matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}DP$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix such that the eigenvalues of $A$ appear in the diagonal of $D$.

How do I find $P$ via Mathematica? Is there a suitable command?

Thanks!
I checked the help section in Mathematica and didn't find such a command.

Comment: `JordanDecomposition[`$A$`]` returns $\{P^{-1},D\}$. (See [`DiagonalizableMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalizableMatrixQ.html).)

Comment: To make Sneeze's hint more explicit: unless you're absolutely sure your matrix is diagonalizable (symmetric, normal, etc.), use `JordanDecomposition[]`.

Comment: Check. Documentation. For. `Eigensystem`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

example:

```
m = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
DiagonalizableMatrixQ@m
True


{d, pt} = Eigensystem@m;
p = Transpose@pt;
p . DiagonalMatrix[d] . Inverse[p]
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}


{s, j} = JordanDecomposition@m;(* returns {P^-1,D} *)
s . j . Inverse@s (* P^(-1).D.P *)
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
```